# Kafka Consumer for Spark written in Scala for Kafka API 0.10: custom AVRO deserializer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am upgrading my Spark Scala App Kafka API to v. 0.10. I used to create custom method for deserialization of the message which comes in byte string format.

I have realized there is a way to pass StringDeserializer or ByteArrayDeserializer as parameter to either key or value.

However,I can not find any information on how to create custom Avro schema deserializer so my kafkaStream can use it when I createDirectStream and consume data from Kafka.

is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. You need to override the `Deserializer<T>` interface defined in `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization` and you need to point `key.deserializer` or `value.deserializer` to your custom class via the `ConsumerStrategy[K, V]` class which holds the Kafka parameters. For example:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer

class AvroDeserializer extends Deserializer[Array[Byte]] {
  override def configure(map: util.Map[String, _], b: Boolean): Unit = ???
  override def close(): Unit = ???
  override def deserialize(s: String, bytes: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = ???
}
```

And then:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import my.location.with.AvroDeserializer

val ssc: StreamingContext = ???
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[AvroDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("sometopic")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, MyTypeWithAvroDeserializer](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
```