# KafkaUtils.createDirectStream does not take right parameters - Spark Streaming + Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, twitter4j

I have an application which sends serialized Twitter data to a Kafka topic. All good so far.

The consumer application should read data and deserialize it. Now, when I call `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`, I think I put the right parameters (as you will see inside the thrown error), so I can't understand why it is not working.

> The method createDirectStream(JavaStreamingContext, Class -K-,
>   Class -V-, Class -KD-, Class -VD-, Map -String,String-, Set -String-) in
>   the type KafkaUtils is not applicable for the arguments
>   (JavaStreamingContext, Class-String-, Class-Status-,
>   Class -StringDeserializer-, Class -StatusDeserializer-,
>   Map-String,String-, Set-String-)

Checking the Spark [Javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html), my params still seem right to me.

My code is:

```
Set<String> topics = new HashSet<>();
topics.add("twitter-test");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(jsc, new Duration(duration));
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
//some properties...
JavaPairInputDStream messages =  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class, Status.class, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class, stream_data.StatusDeserializer.class, props, topics);
```

Status serializer code:

```
public class StatusSerializer implements Serializer<Status> {

  @Override public byte[] serialize(String s, Status o) {

           try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                oos.writeObject(o);
                oos.close();
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                return b;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return new byte[0];
            }
        }

      @Override public void close() {

      }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is with "stream_data.StatusDeserializer.class". Can you please the code of this custom deserializer class. Also, can you please look into this [Kafka Consumer for Spark written in Scala for Kafka API 0.10: custom AVRO deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012741/kafka-consumer-for-spark-written-in-scala-for-kafka-api-0-10-custom-avro-deseri) .

Include the below in the KafkaParam arguments.

```
key.deserializer -> classOf[StringDeserializer]
value.deserializer -> classOf[StatusDeserializer]
```